# GO-QT Binding g++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-marm’

Tags: qt, go, raspberry-pi

I am using QT Binding/Wrapper for Go in my project. Project is compiling fine for amd64 but when I try to compile project for arm devices, it gives me below error

```
 github.com/therecipe/qt/core
# github.com/therecipe/qt/core
 g++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-marm’
```

---

Please find below my go environment variables setup

```
GOARCH="arm"
GOBIN=""
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/home/minhaj/GoLang"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
GCCGO="gccgo"
GOARM=""
CC="arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -marm -pthread -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-
 map=/tmp/go-build277718108=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
```

Comment: Have you tried setting `CC_FOR_TARGET` or `CXX_FOR_TARGET`? See https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/

Comment: @JimB No, I did not try these variables CC_FOR_TARGET or CXX_FOR_TARGET... CC_FOR_TARGET is equal to CC and CXX_FOR_TARGET is equal to CXX